# Facebook real-time update sometimes not sending to the server

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, afnetworking

Facebook real-time update sometimes not sending to the server when the updates are sent from the phone over LTE or 3G. When updates are posted via wifi there is no issues.

Real-time updates are delayed by 5-10secs from updates from PC/wifi. However, sometimes the updates never come when posts are posted via LTE data.

Comment: If that’s reproducible, then file a bug report with Facebook. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs